# Custom Loss function, Keras \\ ValueError: No gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, object, keras

I'm attempting to wrap my Keras neural network in a `class` object. I have implemented the below outside of a class setting, but I want to make this more object-friendly.
To summarize, my `model` calls function `sequential_model` which creates a `sequential` model. Within the `compile` step, I have defined my own loss function `weighted_categorical_crossentropy` which I want the sequential model to implement.
However, when I run the code below I get the following error: `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:`

I suspect the issue is with how I'm defining the `weighted_categorical_crossentropy` function for its use by `sequential`.

Again, I was able to get this work in a non-object oriented way. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, backend as K

class MyNetwork(): 
        
    def __init__(self, file, n_output=4, n_hidden=20, epochs=3,
                 dropout=0.10, batch_size=64, metrics = ['categorical_accuracy'],
                 optimizer = 'rmsprop', activation = 'softmax'):

    [...] //Other Class attributes
 
    def model(self):
        self.model = self.sequential_model(False)
        self.model.summary()


    def sequential_model(self, val):
        K.clear_session()
        if val == False:
            self.epochs = 3
        regressor = Sequential()
        #regressor.run_eagerly = True
        regressor.add(LSTM(units = self.n_hidden, dropout=self.dropout, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (self.X.shape[1], self.X.shape[2])))
        regressor.add(LSTM(units = self.n_hidden, dropout=self.dropout, return_sequences = True))
        regressor.add(Dense(units = self.n_output, activation=self.activation))
    
        self.weights = np.array([0.025,0.225,0.78,0.020])

        regressor.compile(optimizer = self.optimizer, loss = self.weighted_categorical_crossentropy(self.weights), metrics = [self.metrics])
        regressor.fit(self.X, self.Y*1.0,batch_size=self.batch_size, epochs=self.epochs, verbose=1, validation_data=(self.Xval, self.Yval*1.0))

        return regressor

    def weighted_categorical_crossentropy(self, weights):
        weights = K.variable(weights)
        def loss(y_true, y_pred):
            y_pred /= K.sum(y_pred, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
            y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1 - K.epsilon())
            loss = y_true * K.log(y_pred) * weights
            loss = -K.sum(loss, -1)
            return loss
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with above code, but the most noticeable one is you don't return the `loss` from `weighted_categorical_crossentropy`. It should look more like:

```py
    def weighted_categorical_crossentropy(self, weights):
        weights = K.variable(weights)
        def loss(y_true, y_pred):
            y_pred /= K.sum(y_pred, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
            y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1 - K.epsilon())
            loss = y_true * K.log(y_pred) * weights
            loss = -K.sum(loss, -1)
            return loss
        return loss # Return the callable function!
```

The error is `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable` because the loss *method* doesn't return anything, it returns None! If you try to fit a method with `loss=None`, the model will have no way of computing gradients and therefore it will throw the same exact error.

Next up is the that you are using `return_sequences = True` in the layer right before a non-recurrent layer. This causes the `Dense` layer to be called on mis-shaped data, that's appropriate only for recurrent layers. Don't use it like that.
If you have a good reason for using the `return_sequences = True`, then you must add `Dense` layer like:

```py
model.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(...)))
```

This will cause the `Dense` layer to act on output sequence on *every* time step *separately*. This also means that your `y_true` must be of appropriate shape.

There could be other problems with the custom loss function that you defined, but I can not deduce the input/output shapes, so you will have to run it and add see if it works. There will probably be matrix multiplication shape mismatch.

Last but not least, think about using the Sub-classing API. Could it make any of your operations easier to write?

Thanks for reading and I'll update this answer once I have that info. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that obvious logic error and appreciate your thorough response! Re your second point, my output of `y_true` is a `n X time X classes` matrix (in this case: `n X 20 X 4`), thus why the `n_hidden` is of size 20 and `n_output` is of 4 distinct classes. The hidden size of 20 means 20 sequential period of modeling (in order per every n), and so from your point above, it looks like I should have define the `dense` layer as you mentioned. Re your third point, will have to look into a `sub-classing API`. Thanks again, would treat you to some good kinkhali if possible.

Comment: My pleasure @Josh. Glad to help.   
Also, about that knikali: If you somehow decide to visit Georgia one day, I'd be more than happy to invite you at local sakhinkle (name of a place where it is served). Cheers. :)

Comment: It's only a matter of time, my wife is from Poti and I've been instructed to visit Bakhmaro as soon as possible :D

Comment: hey @tornikeo, hope you're well. You're kind of the expert I know in this field, would truly appreciate if you could take a look at another one of my ANN questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65067446/loss-function-not-improving-with-epochs-custom-loss-function

Comment: Hey @Josh I'm fine. How are you? I have some errands to run today and as soon as I get some free time on my hands, I'll try to answer your question. I already bookmarked it.

Comment: Anyway I can get your email (or dummy email), I'm preparing a google colab and I don't want to take the chance of providing public access to my drive (trying to make as private as I can). If not, I can try to find a work-around. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Email me at tonop15@freeuni.edu.ge - that's an old university email address of mine. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! Please look an email with subject "Stackoverflow: Josh Query". I just sent it with the colab link, etc.